# C - Staticaly link GLFW in Makefile MinGW32 - Windows10

Tags: c, opengl, makefile, mingw, static-linking

It is my first time trying to link external libraries to a C file. I read that I can use a Makefile and this is what I have:

```
all: src/main.c
    gcc src/main.c -o main.exe -IC:\src\C\GameTry\dependencies\include -LC:\src\C\GameTry\dependencies\lib -lglfw3 -lgdi32 -lglew32s

clean:
    rm *.o
```

The reason I included `-lgdi32` is beacuse the official glfw documentation states that:

> When using MinGW to link an application with the static version of GLFW, you must also explicitly link with gdi32

This makefile works but OpenGL throws the warning `corrupt .drectve at end of def file` repeatedly many times and it throws `undefined reference to '__security_cookie'` error may times aswell which causes the program to not compile.
I have looked all arround the internet and haven't been able to find an answer. I believe these errors have something to do with the default MSVN libraries but I'm not sure

[image: VScode terminal errors]

Comment: "but OpenGL throws the warning " no, OpenGL does nothing of this sort. The errors you get come from your linker, not OpenGL. No idea what versions of the glfw libs you are using, but it doesn't seem to be the right one.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `libglfw3.a` that matches your compiler and platform (make sure to not mix win32 and win64), then a `.def` file should not be needed.

Somehow the linker is picking up a `.def` file anyway.

If there is a `.def` for glfw3, can you try to remove or rename it and try again?